# Guice MapBinder

Tags: java, dependency-injection, kotlin, guice

I'm using Guice in Java + Kotlin project to inject map of algorithm implementation into a specific bean but I keep getting

```
1) No implementation for java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends com.scherule.scheduling.algorithms.SchedulingAlgorithm> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=scheduling.algorithms) was bound.
  while locating java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends com.scherule.scheduling.algorithms.SchedulingAlgorithm> annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=scheduling.algorithms)
    for the 2nd parameter of com.scherule.scheduling.SchedulingJobConsumer.<init>(SchedulingJobConsumer.kt:17)
  while locating com.scherule.scheduling.SchedulingJobConsumer
```

The definition of the module is defined like this:

```
class AlgorithmsModule : AbstractModule() {

    override fun configure() {
        MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(),
                String::class.java,
                SchedulingAlgorithm::class.java,
                Names.named("scheduling.algorithms")
        ).addBinding("interval-projection").toInstance(IntervalProjectionAlgorithm())
    }

}
```

And the caller code is:

```
@Singleton
class SchedulingJobConsumer
@Inject constructor(
        @Named("scheduling.channel") channel: Channel,
        @Named("scheduling.algorithms") val schedulers: Map<String, SchedulingAlgorithm>
) : DefaultConsumer(channel) ...
```

But when I do

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Map<String, SchedulingAlgorithm>>() {}, named("scheduling.algorithms")))
```

it is there. What's wrong?

Comment: Try adding the `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation to the declaration of `val schedulers`

Comment: Adding it to constructor declaration doesn't change anything. Doing this on a field modifies the error message to No implementation for java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.scherule.scheduling.algorithms.SchedulingAlgorithm> (...) So it appears it cannot even find this one.

Comment: the error message seems to say that it couldn't find an implementation for SchedulingAlgorithm.  how is that defined?

Comment: IntervalProjectionAlgorithm is the only implementation bound as you can see in the first code snippet. And it cannot find a map not a schedulingAlgorithm, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the fact Kotlin Generics != Java Generics.

This Kotlin code.

```
 @Named("scheduling.algorithms") val schedulers: Map<String, SchedulingAlgorithm>
```

Gets compiled as

```
Map<String, ? extends SchedulingAlgorithm> and not Map<String, SchedulingAlgorithm>
```

When injecting Guice is looking for `Map<String, ? extends SchedulingAlgorithm>` for which it has no binding as the `MapBinder` created the binding for `Map<String, SchedulingAlgorithm>`.

Comment: Thanks, adding @JvmSuppressWildcards to the parameter that expects injection let me get around this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `MapBinder` you can try to add the following member method to your `AlgorithmsModule`:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("scheduling.algorithms")
fun schedulingAlgorithms(): Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards SchedulingAlgorithm> {
    return IntervalProjectionAlgorithm()
}
```

Comment: I think the annotation needs to be on the parameter Guice is trying to inject, not the on the @Provides method.